# Old Windows 10 BitLocker SSD does not boot after cloning from it with gddrescue in Linux

Tags: windows-10, boot, bitlocker, ddrescue

I have a problem booting my dad's HP computer after *copying* data from its SSD to a new SSD. Neither the old, nor the new one boots. Please help, I am afraid I may have lost all my data. I need the computer to boot again normally.

TDLR: copied data using `ddrescue` from old to new SSD, now both SSDs won't boot. It's a Windows 10 drive with BitLocker.

Error is blue screen with `0xc000000e` error.

HP computer: HP ProDesk 400 G4 Small Form Factor

Here is what I did:

1. I have a 256 GB SSD and bought a 1TB SSD.
2. I created an Ubuntu USB disk and booted the computer with it to copy all the data from the old to the new SSD.
3. I used an older Sata-to-USB-2.0 adapter to connect the new drive.
4. I used the following command: `ddrescue -f -n --ask /dev/<old> /dev/<new> /path/to/log`
5. It took way too long, so I hit Ctrl+C
6. I connected both drives using SATA to a different, newer computer and performed the same command in 10 minutes.

Between steps 5 and 6 I noticed `fdisk` complaining about a missing "GPT backup at end of drive", which I assumed to have been from the halfway-copied-into-SSD. I may have looked wrong and it may have been the old SSD, although the problem wasn't there before any of the copying took place.

Result:
The HP computer will not boot using any of the two drives. Important to note: I only realized my dad uses BitLocker *after* I copied the data. Clearly this is related, but I do not know how to fix the problem.

[image]

Of course I feel like an idiot, I was completely convinced simply copying data off a drive bit-by-bit could do no harm. I am a programmer so I should have known better than NOT to make a backup, but I am convinced I used the `ddrescue` command correctly.

Things I've tried:

1. disable/enable CSM
2. disable/enable secure boot
3. change boot order back to the original (not sure what the original is now anymore...).
4. Create USB windows installation media to somehow get a repair screen to show, but no luck.

Comment: Sounds like the partition table on the source disk was modified.  If that is indeed the case then the files can't be recovered since they are encrypted.

Comment: The new SSD, when connected to a different computer shows up as a bitlocker drive. I do not have the recovery key at the moment, and may not be able to access it. If this is the case, is there a way to make a drive in that state bootable?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to boot? How was Bitlocker secured in the old system via TPB chip (which I assume), via pin, via password or via USB (or a combination)?

Comment: Updated the question, added a picture of the problem.

Comment: F1 and F8 do nothing

Comment: @pancake - If the partition table was modified you will be lucky to get the data off the drive.  I have never been able to recover from that particular error in my 20 years of working with computers.

Comment: I never had this error message myself, but it looks like you might be able to use the repair option from an installation medium. However, if the volume is encrypted, you will need the recovery key.

Comment: I have been able to boot a windows install usb disk, but indeed to do anything repair-wise, I need the recovery key. Hopefully my dad has it in his microsoft account if he has one. It’s 2 AM here. Getting some sleep. Thanks for the help guys, I welcome any other tips on what I can do to diagnose the issue further.

Comment: @Albin I don’t know which method, I know hardly anything about bitlocker. What I do know, the computer normally boots into Windows, and I simply need to login. No password or anything, apart from the Windows account login.

Comment: @pancake good luck, make sure not to recover on the original drive (unless you have a verified clone drive, image, etc. otherwise your data will be gone if s.th. happens to the original and the copy is corrupted)

Comment: I retrieved the recovery from my dad's MS account in the end. I was able to decrypt the volume on the new SSD, run `bootrec /fixmbr` and format and rebuild the EFI partition (`bootrec /fixboot` gave me "permission denied"). Now the computer boots with the new SSD, all data perfectly copied.

Comment: @pancake thanks for the message, it's always nice to hear back from the OP. Glad it worked. I'm sure the possibility all data is lost was hell... I summarized it with an answer, feel free to accept unless you want to write your own answer.

Comment: Accepted your answer, you were correct from the beginning, having the recovery key was essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the "recovery key". Usually it's was stored in a file or with your  Windows account - if you have one. In cooperate settings the domain controller might be setup to store it as well.

Decrypt the volume on the new SSD, run `bootrec /fixmbr` and format the EFI partition. That should make the new SSD boot again.